# Exporting HighCharts chart specific height width

Tags: javascript, highcharts

In order to change the exporting height and width attributes to charts for HighCharts you have to add the exporting parameter:

```
var chart = Highcharts.mapChart('container', {
    title: {
        text: 'USA 2016 Presidential Election Results'
    },

    chart: {
        animation: false
    },

    exporting: { height: 200, width: 700}  //<---- exporting
```

On this following charts I'm having difficulty with this:

https://jsfiddle.net/kmr6kv6L/2/

No matter what I set the height or width, the output just comes back whatever dimension is set by default. Does this chart not follow the same functionality?

The values are just by example but it's not working for other values either.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

according to [Documentation](https://api.highcharts.com/highmaps/exporting.sourceWidth) and [this sample](https://api.highcharts.com/highmaps/exporting.sourceWidth)

> **sourceWidth: Number**
>   The width of the original chart when exported, unless an explicit chart.width is set. The width exported raster image is then multiplied by scale.

Instead of using following exporting options :

```
 exporting: { height: 200, width: 700}  //<---- exporting
```

try this:

```
    exporting: {
        sourceWidth: 700,
        sourceHeight: 400,
    },
```

**EDIT**

In addition to what I said before, you should also set the `scale = 1` like the following:

```
 exporting: {
    sourceWidth: 700,
    sourceHeight: 400,
    scale: 1 
},
```

[jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/kmr6kv6L/25/)